# Process stuck at callback url while auth0 login

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I am working on the React project and integrating auth0 with it. I have completed all the steps but it stuck at one point. When I am going to log in with auth0 using the Gmail account then it stuck on callback URL and the process is stopped `handleAuthentication` method is not called after the callback URL. how can I solve this issue ??

```
export default class Auth {
  auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth({
    domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
    clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
    responseType: 'token id_token',
    scope: 'openid'
  });

  constructor() {
    console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV',process.env.NODE_ENV)
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
    this.isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticated.bind(this);
  }

  login() {
    this.auth0.authorize();
    console.log('login done',store)
  }

  handleAuthentication() {
    console.log('asdfasfasf')
    this.auth0.parseHash((err, authResult) => {
      console.log('authResult.accessToken',authResult.accessToken)
      if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
        this.setSession(authResult);
        localStorage.setItem("user_id", "user-id");
        let store1 = store();
        store1.dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS', payload: authResult })
        window.location.replace('/')
      } else if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        alert(`Error: ${err.error}. Check the console for further details.`);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: What is value of `redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl`?

Comment: @MiroslavSaracevic I have updated actually auth details I am getting from another file

Comment: so where did you say that you want `handleAuthentication` to fire up when going to your callback url?

Comment: haven't used auth0. but would expect to see `app.use('/callback', handleAuthentication);` or something

Comment: Check if your system time is not out of sync

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late to answer this question but just in case it helps someone in the future or at least points in the right direction.

I had this same issue and the problem was this line

```
redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
```

If you access localhost as `http://localhost:3000` your existing callback should work.

However, the redirectUrl won't work for `http://www.localhost:3000`. The url will get stuck at callback. I think auth0 component is quite specific about the routing. It does treat a www and one without www differently although they point to the same domain.

In order to make this work for both www and non-www, I changed the redirectUri url to the following

redirectUri: `${window.location.origin}/callback`,

P.S: once this change is made also don't forget to adjust the callback on the auth0 site to allow both variations.